# ¿Como llamar un metodo de una pagina a otra en ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, aplicación-web, asp

Tengo este código en mi página "Busqueda.aspx", que debe de actualizar los datos encontrados en mi base de datos. Sin embargo, necesito llamar a este

```
            public void UpdateBinding()
            {
                string producto = Request.QueryString["producto"];
                listaencontrados.DataSource = producto;
                listaencontrados.DataTextField = "fullinfo";

            }
```

Lo logré facil en WindowsForms porque mi boton de buscar y mi lista de encontrados están en el mismo Form, mientras que mi boton de busqueda está en mi masterpage accesible desde cualquier pagina del dominio. Leí que puedo hacer una clase para llamarla desde cada página. El problema es que el método le dice al listbox que escriba ciertos valores y no se como hacer eso desde una clase, si es que es posible.

Comment: donde realizas la consulta a a base de datos ? porque pones el boton en la master page si el lisbox esta en la page, eso no tiene sentido. Una clase como mencionas no aplica, salvo que sea una clase de acceso a datos que devuelva como respuesta los resultados de la consulta a la db, pero no accede a ningun control del webform

Comment: Pongo el boton en la masterpage para que quede accesible desde cualquier página. Si, desde el principio pensé en que podría ser ilógico meter algo así en la master, pero no supe en donde mas hacerlo, por ahora, creo que haré todo desde una sola página, para demostrar que funciona. Mientras, esperaré a ver si hay mas respuestas.